# How to write a polynomial in standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How does one write the polynomial $p(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^3+(-\frac{3}{2})x^2+1$ using the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ ?

Comment: $p(x)=\frac12 x^3+\left(-\frac32\right) x^2+0x+1$.

Comment: That's it? For some reason I imagined I had to do something substantially more complex.

Comment: Nope, that's it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It writes itself! Specifically, you want to represent $p(x)$ as a linear combination of the polynomials $1,x,x^2$, and $x^3$, which simply means that you want to write it in the form $$c_0\cdot1+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3$$ for some scalars $c_0,c_1,c_2$, and $c_3$. And the polynomial $p(x)$ itself does just that:

$$p(x)=1\cdot1+0\cdot x+\left(-\frac32\right)x^2+\frac12x^3\;,$$

with coefficients $1,0,-\frac32$, and $\frac12$.

Comment: Couldn't be more clear. Thank you! (Will accept your answer as soon as stackexchange lets me)

Comment: @user1132363: You’re welcome!